# Using VPN to connect local office resources to odoo webserver

Tags: vpn, openvpn, odoo

We have a odoo server hosted online. We need to have CUPS and an  asterisk pbx linked to said server. Would it be appropriate to have that same odoo server host openvpn, and have the office router connect to it via said VPN? Would that interfere with the public facing website at all?

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN server is not CPU / Server intensive app.
Server with Odoo & OpenVPN can easily handle its traffic in a medium company environment.
And I do not see any issues in this setup regarding interference with public website.

P.S. For asterisk see this application - https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/asterisk_calls/.